# How can I get the terminal window to open in the centre of the screen?

Tags: unity, 16.10, window-manager

I am using Unity on Ubuntu 16.10.

When I open a terminal, the window appears in the top left corner.

How can I get it to open in the center of the screen?

Comment: Near duplicate of 143422

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--geometry charsxline+x+y` to select both size and position of a program, like gnome-terminal.  Adjust the x and y to fix your display, they are in pixels.  Edit the file `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` adding to the "Exec" line, for example:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry 130x24+500+400
```

Save and exit.
Close all existing open terminals, and the new ones will have the selected geometry.